# Subgroup Boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm trying to make a graphic that will show three things side-by-side. First is to show change in the individual over time. Next is to show change in their peer group over time. Last is to show change in the overall population over time.

I have four time points on each observation. What I'd like to see is two sets of boxplots next to each other, one for the peer group and one for the population. Overlaid on each of these would the datapoints for a given individual. Each set would show data at time1, time2, time3, and time4. The overlayed points would convey where the individuals had been at each time, so the information can be conveyed in two sets of boxplots.

Here is code to simulate the sort of data I am working with, and my ineffective attempt at creating my plot.

```
peer <- c(rep(1, 15), rep(2, 41))
year <- rep(c(1, 2), 28)
pct <- rep(1:8, 7)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(peer, year, pct))

ggplot(dat, aes(peer==1, pct)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(. ~ year)
```

I don't think my `ggplot` approach is even close to correct. Please help!

Here's a sketch of what I'm trying to do.

[image: sample]

Comment: It's unclear what you want to show. You say you want the individual, peer groups, and overall population side by side. But then you say you want 2 sets of boxplots, one for the peer group and one for population. Please reword your question so it's clear what you want.

Comment: Perhaps mock-up a simple sketch of the desired output?

Comment: Sorry about that, @Synergist. I can see how that would be confusing. I added a sentence to the second paragraph to clarify.

Comment: @MrFlick: I couldn't post it here directly, but I uploaded an example to Imgur and linked it. Good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this close to what you had in mind? There's a boxplot for each value of `peer` for each `year`. I've also included the mean values for each group.

```
# Boxplots for each combination of year and peer, with means superimposed
ggplot(dat, aes(year, pct, group=interaction(year,peer), colour=factor(peer))) + 
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0.4), width=0.4) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", position=position_dodge(width=0.4), 
               aes(group=peer)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", position=position_dodge(width=0.4), size=4, 
               aes(group=peer)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(dat$year))
```

[image]

You can add a population boxplot, but then the plot starts to look cluttered:

```
# Add population boxplot (not grouped by peer)
ggplot(dat, aes(year, pct, group=interaction(year,peer), colour=factor(peer))) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=year), width=0.05, colour="grey60", fill="#FFFFFF90") +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0.4), width=0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", position=position_dodge(width=0.4), 
               aes(group=peer)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", position=position_dodge(width=0.4), size=4, 
               aes(group=peer)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(dat$year))
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment, maybe something like this:

```
# Add an ID variable to the data
dat$id = rep(1:(nrow(dat)/2), each=2)

library(gridExtra) # For grid.arrange function

pdf("plots.pdf", 7, 5)
for (i in unique(dat$id)) {
  p1 = ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(data=dat[dat$peer==unique(dat$peer[dat$id==i]),],
                 aes(year, pct, group=year)) +
    geom_point(data=dat[dat$id==i,], aes(year, pct), 
               pch=8, colour="red", size=5) +
    ggtitle("Your Peers")

  p2 = ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(data=dat, aes(year, pct, group=year)) +
    geom_point(data=dat[dat$id==i,], aes(year, pct), 
               pch=8, colour="red", size=5) +
    ggtitle("All Participants")

    grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2, main=paste0("ID = ", i))
}
dev.off()
```

Here's what the first plot looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to what I have in mind, but for each individual I only want to show them their own peer group's boxplot. I just posted an example [here](http://imgur.com/JtiSoue). Also, I wish I could give you points by voting, but I just made an account here and am not allowed to yet.